# Default textField in a status item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, statusbar

I have a text field inside a status item and would like for it to be immediately active when the status item is clicked. I tried the usual `becomeFirstResponder` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then in `awakeFromNib`, but it didn't work. I imagine t's because the status item's menu is not open when those methods get called at launch, possibly ignoring it. Then I tried to set an action when the status item was clicked, but someone here told me that those actions can only be executed if the status item doesn't have a dropdown menu, which mine does. What I want is for the status item to be clicked, and the dropdown menu to appear with the textfield activated so typing can begin immediately. I'm using a custom view to show the textfield in the menu, not sure if that's relevant but maybe something else is supposed to be used in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an object as the `delegate` of the status item's menu, implement the `‑menuWillOpen:` delegate method and then use `‑performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:modes:` to set the first responder.

This will ensure that the call to make the text field the first responder happens in the next run through the event loop, after the menu has opened. You need to pass in `NSRunLoopCommonModes` or `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` in the array of run loop modes passed to the `modes:` parameter, because the normal `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method will not call the selector until the menu is closed.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightField) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
}

- (void)highlightField
{
    [[yourTextField window] makeFirstResponder:yourTextField];
}
```

Comment: That at least got an action to perform when I clicked the status item, but [[yourTextField window] makeFirstResponder:yourTextField]; didn't work. I made the method put a 5 in the text field to see if it was working, when it opened nothing happened, but when I closed it and opened it again the 5 was there. It seems to be working almost like menuDidClose. Not sure what's going on...

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the `‑performSelector:withObject:delay:modes` method instead. You need to schedule the method call in the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` runloop mode if you want it to occur during menu tracking. I've updated the answer.